# SQL com dados associados no Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Eu tenho as seguintes tabelas abaixo relacionadas

**Produtos**

- id
- produto
- valor
- validade

**Consultas**

- id
- user_id

**Consultas_Produtos**

- id
- consulta_id
- produto_id

Sempre que um usuário realiza uma consulta, é salvo o histórico na tabela `consultas` e os respectivos produtos consultados na tabela `consultas_produtos` através do relacionamento.

Como posso construir uma `SQL` que ao listar os produtos de acordo com os parâmetros de consulta, retorno somente os produtos que ***nunca foram consultados pelo usuário***?

Comment: Você tem ai a consulta que está fazendo???

Comment: $produtos = Produto::where('valor', '>=', $valor)->get(); Isto irá retornar todos os produtos que possuam o valor maior que o especificado. Eu preciso retornar somente os produtos que nunca foram consultas pelo usuário verificando o histórico através da associação.

Comment: Qual é a versão? do seu Laravel? é importante essa informação.

Comment: A minha versão do Laravel é a 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode ser utilizado o método [join](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins) e no final um [where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses) para filtrar usuários, exemplo:

```php
$p = Produto::join('consultas_produtos','produtos.id','=','consultas_produtos.produto_id') 
               ->join('consultas','consultas_produtos.consulta_id','=','consultas.id') 
               ->where('consultas.user_id','<>', $user_id)
               ->get();
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Query - Joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins)
- [Query - Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: Desta forma não funcionaria, pois os usuários que nunca fizeram a consulta de um produto (abacaxi, por exemplo) não poderiam fazer a consulta do mesmo, pois algum usuário já o consultou.

Comment: @MaxPorcento a sua pergunta diz Produto? ou estou enganado? e o que não deu certo? A pergunta é essa: `Como posso construir uma SQL que ao listar os produtos ...` Com certeza está faltando dados na sua pergunta

Comment: @MaxPorcento outro coisa pela seu comentário, existe uma grande confusão quem consulta em que já consultou, estou sem entender.

Comment: O método 'doesnHave' não retornaria no SQL os produtos que já foram consultados (pois os mesmos já possuem um registro na tabela 'consultas_produtos'). Entretanto, digamos que o usuário A consulte o produto abacaxi, pois está dentro da faixa de preço estipulada por ele. A consulta será realizada e o relacionamento salvo. Utilizando o método proposto, quando ele realizar uma nova consulta utilizando a mesma faixa de preço, o produto abacaxi não será retornando. Mas desta forma se um usuário B fizer a mesma consulta do usuário A ele não retornaria o produto abacaxi, certo?

Comment: @MaxPorcento então você precisa fazer um INNER JOIN das tabelas e no final fazer um filtro pelo campo `user_id` `<>` o valor, realmente a pesquisa fica restritiva ao relacionamento e não vai satisfazer o que precisa.

Comment: Quando um usuário realiza uma consulta é regitrado na tabela 'consulta' o id do usuário e os parâmetros que ele usou. Na tabela 'consultas_produtos' é registrado o id da tabela 'consulta' junto ao id de cada produto consultado pelo usuário. Eu preciso verificar quais produtos aquele usuário já consultou para não retornalos em consultas futiras. O método que você propos funciona perfeitamente para isto, entretanto, se user_2 fizer uma consulta com os mesmos parâmetros já utilizados pelo user_1, ele não irá retornar os produtos que ainda não foram pesquisados pelo user_2.

Comment: Eu fiz a alteração @MaxPorcento

Comment: @MaxPorcento deu certo a solução?